# Square crop an image from image picker Activiy

Tags: android

I have two methods that pick pictures for me. I want to do something like the Facebook profile picture square crop after choosing the picture. And was wandering if there is easy way like putting extras to the intent ("crop", "true"), ("aspectX/Y",1) and such. Right now I am experimenting with the intent extras, but can't make it work.

Constants.TAKE_CAMERA_PICTURE is 1000
Constants.SELECT_PICTURE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE is 1001

```
private void takeCameraPhoto() {
    mPhotoHelper = PhotoHelper.recycle(mPhotoHelper);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Uri photoUri = Uri.fromFile(mPhotoHelper.getPhotoFile());
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.TAKE_CAMERA_PICTURE);
}

public void importPhotoAlbum() {
    mPhotoHelper = PhotoHelper.recycle(mPhotoHelper);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.SELECT_PICTURE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use this lib. you can do better than current. https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using **jdamcd/android-crop** library for this purpose. Just add this in your project as library..
Now to crop image just write one line i-e

```
Crop.of(source, dest).asSquare().start(this, CropCode);
```

here,
*source* is Uri of image file, *dest* is destination uri where image to be saved

It will do all the work for you.. Also there are other ways for cropping. Let me know if there is any difficulty for you :-)

Comment: for that, you need to do something like this.

Crop.of(source, dest).asSquare().withAspect(x,y).start(this, CropCode);

Where x and y are int based aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure Android SDK , use the **Bitmap** class with the **createBitmap** method , check the docs [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) , and check this example :

```
Bitmap croppedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceImage, startX, startY, destinationWidth, destinationHeight);
```

If you want to use Third party SDK, Take a look at this library [Cropper](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper) **Android widget for cropping and rotating an image**  ,i think it will do what you want ,check their [wiki](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper/wiki) page with the following example :

1- add the CropImageView to your Layout XML file

```
<com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView 
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

2- you can modify attributes programmatically by using provided CropImageView methods:

```
CropImageView cropImageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.CropImageView);
cropImageView.setAspectRatio(5, 10);
cropImageView.setFixedAspectRatio(true);
cropImageView.setGuidelines(1);
```

3- To retrieve the image contained within the Cropper window, use the provided method getCroppedImage() to retrieve a Bitmap of the cropped image.

```
croppedImage = cropImageView.getCroppedImage();
ImageView croppedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.croppedImageView);
croppedImageView.setImageBitmap(croppedImage);
```

Hope That Helps.